# Can we synonymize [rdp] and [remote-desktop]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Both [rdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdp) (824 questions) and [remote-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) (1098 questions) tags exist. They appear to have been created around the same time, and have the exact same Tag Wiki excerpt:

> Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) is a proprietary protocol developed by Microsoft, which provides a user with a graphical interface to another computer.

The [rdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdp) tag wiki has more information, while the [remote-desktop] tag wiki has no info.

Considering this, can we please synonymize them?

Comment: what will be the master ? Is that even on-topic?

Comment: @rene I do not have a preference but I suppose since [tag:rdp] has more info in the wiki, that it should be the master. And no I don't think it's on-topic, but burninating it would be a lot easier if we reduced the number of questions by half, first...

Comment: When Teamviewer started using RDP? When VirtualBox started using it? Apart of both being protocols for remote control of a desktop, what has RDP to do with VNC? I've found questions about all those topics on the remote desktop tag...

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure what Teamviewer or VirtualBox using RDP have to do with this request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498877/how-is-teamviewer-so-fast https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547805/oracle-virtualbox-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966831/connecting-ubuntu-using-vnc

Comment: You are requesting for synonymization as if both tags mean the same, well, they at least aren't used the same way.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree; they appear to be used the exact same way considering their tag wiki excerpts are *identical*. These are two tags for the exact same thing. If a question is using one of these tags for something other than the RDP, then it's probably a misuse of the tag. They've both had the same wiki since April 2012.

Comment: The tag wiki can say *whatever you want*, if it isn't actually enforced, then is dead letter. Likewise, there are many tags that says "DO NOT USE", yet they are being used...

Comment: @Braiam So if you think the tag wikis are wrong and we shouldn't merge them because of that, you should go edit the tag wikis to be right. Tag wikis that say DO NOT USE are subjects of burnination procedures.

Comment: Well for remote desktop to be "right", it has to have the most generic text possible "use for question related to remote desktop", which would be promptly and correctly rejected since "**[s]imply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it** unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. "

Comment: @Braiam So like I said, if that's the case then those questions are improperly using the tag. That's not a defense against merging the two tags.

Comment: So, you prefer a single rift raft tag that nobody can use instead of one tag that clearly defines what it's for and it's used as such and another rift raft? Sorry, but this makes a manageable matter worse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168871/discussion-between-tylerh-and-braiam).